# access parent class scope in usort function

Tags: php, class, scope

Is it possible to access the parent class's methods in this scenario, using `usort()`?

```
class MyClass {    
    public function isGreater($old,$new){
        return ($new - old > 0) ? true : false;
    }

    public function load($data){
        usort($data,function($a,$b){
            return $this->isGreater($a,$b) ? 1 : -1; // THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE
        }
    }
}
```

I'm assuming since usort is using its own function scope, i can't access the public method `isGreater()`. Is there any way to do this? I can turn that method into a static function if it helps...

Answer (score 4):

To access variables in an outer scope in an anonymous function, you need to use the `use` declaration:

```
public function load($data){
    $self = $this;
    usort($data,function($a,$b) use ($self){
        return $self->isGreater($a,$b) ? 1 : -1; // THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE
    }
}
```

I've created a local variable `$self` because older versions of PHP don't allow accessing `$this` in a closure.

Comment: Good ol' PHP. No lexical scope, but hey look: closures.